# SSH and FTP work through PuTTy and Filezilla but not Zend studio

Tags: authentication, ssh, subdomain

I have the SSH key and login name. I can use those credentials to login through PuTTy and use another username and pw for Filezilla and it works correctly. I am trying to use these credentials to log into the a subdomain through Zend Studio. The error is

```
RSEG1066

Failed to connect sshd on "xx.xx.xx.xx:22"

Auth Fail
```

I have added the SSH key in Windows->Preferences->Network Connections->SSH2 Private Keys. I added both the pem and ppk. Other ssh connections work to different servers but none will work to this server through zend studio(tested eclipse as well). What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the public key, private key and the pem.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't know what the "pem" is and where I have to add it...